# JavaScript: Как работает сравнение с одновременным присваиванием?

Tags: javascript, сравнение

Объясните, пожалуйста, как и почему этот код работает:

```
let old_val : number = 0;
const check = (new_val: number) : boolean => old_val === (old_val = new_val);
```

По идее, в моём понимании, сначала должна выполниться операция присваивания, после которой в переменную **old_val** запишется значение **new_val** и сама операция присваивания вернёт обновленное значение **old_val** для последующего сравнения. Но к моменту сравнения **old_val** уже должна быть равна **new_val**, и потому данная функция всегда должна возвращать **true**.
Однако эта конструкция работает иначе. Она возвращает **true**, если значение старое, и **false**, если значение новое и обновляет старое.
Я не могу понять как она работает на уровне операций с памятью.

Comment: Вероятно, это вопрос всё-таки не про typescript, а про javascript

Comment: (а вообще в коде обращение к несуществующей переменной old_val, на что закономерно ругается typescript-компилятор)

Comment: old_value объявлено в самой первой строке. TS компилятор ни на что не ругается. Код работает как мне и надо. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю почему он так работает.

Comment: Переменную old_value вы нигде не используете, а переменная old_val не существует, код не работает

Comment: Но ладно, представим что переменная old_val существует, тогда в спецификации ECMAScript в описании оператора `===` ([13.11 Equality Operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-equality-operators)) чётко прописано, что сперва вычисляется значение левой части, а потом значение правой части. Если вы поменяете их местами `(old_val = new_val) === old_val` тогда функция станет возвращать всегда true (при условии что вы всё-таки создадите переменную old_val)

Comment: Я опечатался,  old_value -> old_val
Ваш ответ мне помог. Сравнение происходит со значением в стеке, куда помещается результат вычисления левой части, а не со значением переменной old_val на момент сравнения.
Благодарю.